# Meaning of notation $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(X,Y)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that given $U,V$ vector spaces over $F$ field, $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{F}}(U,V)$ is the set of linear transformations mapping $U$ to $V$.

(1) What does $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Set}}(X,Y)$ mean?

(2) Are homomorphisms between sets just functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) It is the set of functions/maps $X \longrightarrow Y$.

(2) Yes, by definition homomorphisms between algebraic structures are functions which preserve the structure. Since sets have an empty structure, the homomorphisms are just functions.

More generally, if $\mathcal{C}$ is any category, then $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$ denotes the set of morphisms from $X$ to $Y$ in the category $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. For some reason I thought Hom referred to homomorphisms, and I wasn't seeing anything about what they are when $C$ changes. Wiki page on morphisms is much clearer about this.

Comment: homomorphism = morphism.

Comment: @manofbear: Some authors use $\mathrm{Mor}$ for the categorical sense. Many categorical terms and notations came from algebra, including $\mathrm{Hom}$, mono- and epimorphism, product and sum (coproduct), etc. Note that even in concrete categories ("sets with structure") they can differ the original algebraic notion (popular example is the ring inclusion $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Q$, which is a non-surjective epimorphism).